# How to move files and folder from a batch file command by just changing the directory structure just like it does from drag-n-drop of windows explorer

Tags: performance, batch-file, copy, drag, robocopy

When we move a large file or folder using drag and drop inside the windows explorer (within the same drive) it happens very fast. This is because, i believe the files or folders are not actually moved on the hard disk but just the folder path is changed inside the directory structure of the drive.
So is there a way to do the same from a batch file command.

I tried robocopy /e /move myFolder
but this takes a long time to move as probably it is copying the file first on the hard disk and then deleting.

Any way of doing this?

Comment: The `move` command does exactly that: not touching the files themselves, just adapting their handles (the "pointers" in the FAT (File Allocation Table). Think of `move` like an enhanced "ren" command. (you are right, `robocopy`, `xcopy` and `copy` actually read and write the files' contents)

Comment: oh thanks Stephan.. probably i skipped that command as i wanted to use the latest option available i.e. robocopy and assumed that the 'robocopy /move' option will perform similar to the move command.